# Touchpad gets stuck on a Dell Vostro 3450

Tags: dell

occasionally my touch-pad freeze and i am unable to use my mouse unless i attach another mouse to the machine
this only happens while running on battery power - not while AC is plugged in (but once it got stuck - connecting to AC does not unstuck it)

the only way i found to unfreeze it is to restart X

the machine is: Dell Vostro 3450, With ubuntu 11.10 64bit installed on it

Comment: i disabled the startup command:
synaptikscfg init
from my account - and so far it seems to work - i have yet to fegure out why

Comment: You might want to put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP found a work around

> i disabled the startup command: synaptikscfg init from my account - and so far it seems to work - i have yet to fegure out why